# index part of column with flexible number of character

Tags: oracle, performance, indexing

I want to index part of a column with value like this : @aaa/453 . it means that the value in this column consist of four parts , symbol character / number . 
in our query we just have Numerical section so we want to have an index on this part. 
the number of character in each part is changeable .

please help me

Comment: You should split the three parts over 3 different columns. Then you can filter efficiently with a regular index.

Comment: @GMB it need very changes in or business and we cant do this right now

Comment: Then create computed columns (using `regexp_substr`) and index these. At a later time you may be able to replace your original column and turn the computed columns into regular ones (and maybe even make the original one a computed column then :-).

Comment: By the way: Do you see a time coming when the situation will alow splitting the column? It is easy to say "We know it's a horrible design, but right now we cannot fix it. We will do so later.", but will there ever come a time when you won't say the very same thing? One time you must bite the bullet, and usually it's the sooner the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example: table contains values similar to what you described.

```
SQL> create table test (col varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test
  2  select '@aaa/453'   from dual union all
  3  select '$bcdxyz/35' from dual union all
  4  select '#gf/203'    from dual;

3 rows created.
```

In order to select rows from the table, one option is to use such a query:

```
SQL> select * from test
  2  where regexp_substr(col, '\d+$') = '35';

COL
--------------------
$bcdxyz/35
```

So, let's create a function-based index:

```
SQL> create index i1test on test (regexp_substr(col, '\d+$'));

Index created.
```

What does the explain plan say?

```
SQL> explain plan for
  2  select * from test
  3  where regexp_substr(col, '\d+$') = '35';

Explained.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 210954056

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |        |     1 |    54 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TEST   |     1 |    54 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | I1TEST |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access( REGEXP_SUBSTR ("COL",'\d+$')='35')

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)

18 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Looks like it might help. Try it, see how it behaves.

Comment: thanks. it work well. please tell me how this regular expression  work ? "regexp_substr(col, '\d+$')"

Comment: You're welcome. That expression returns any number (`+`) of digits (`\d`) that is anchored to the end (`$`) of the `col` column. For example, for `abc#$fe42` it'll return `42`

Comment: No problem; I'm glad if it helped.

Comment: I think this function work well too ,'SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col,'/', -1, 1)+1)' . but I don't  know Which is better in terms of performance issue, special in a table that have many insert ?

Comment: SUBSTR is OK, sure, and - in terms of large data sets - probably will perform better than regular expressions. For not-that-many-rows, regexp *looks* prettier and is somewhat simpler to understand what you're doing, without affecting performance.

Comment: you mean that in a large data set use two function -SUBSTR and INSTR- together is better than one function- regexp- according to performance issue?

Comment: No. I said *probably*. You should measure both options and see which behaves better.